# ng-Show not working from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS but I am starting to like it but I don't know why this isn't working... if you can tell me I'd be most appreciative. I have an `DIV` on my webpage like so

```
<div ng-show="loginUser.notFound">
   Sorry but you aren't found, try again...
</div>
```

In my controller I have the following code:

```
angular.module('myApp.auth')

.controller('AuthCtrl',
    function($scope, userService, authService) {

        $scope.loggedInUser = null;
        $scope.user = null;
        $scope.notFound = true;

        $scope.login = function (loginUser) {

            $scope.notFound = false;

            authService.login(loginUser).then(function(response) {

                if(response === 0){
                    $scope.notFound = true;
                } else{
                    reset();
                }
            });

        };
  // and so on...
```

Now the response is working, if a user is found the response is 1 and all my magic works, if it is 0 I set the `notFound` property to `true` and expect that my DIV is shown on the client/interface. The DIV is not being shown. When I use Batarang I see that the value of `$scope.notFound` is being correctly changed depending on the user input and the backend service (the response), however my DIV is not being shown - where am I going wrong? If I haven't given enough information or I am talking nonsense please say and I will rework the question.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change:

```
<div ng-show="loginUser.notFound">
```

to:

```
<div ng-show="notFound">
```

Comment: Doh! My eyes, my eyes! Thanks a lot, I feel really stupid now!